# Colocar um controle de decisão dentro de uma expressão lambda

Tags: c#, linq, expressões-lambda

Estou construindo essa consulta:

```
private List<string> pegaInformacaoParceiro(string _osparceiro, string _cnpj)
        {
            List<string> lista = new List<string>();
            WEBEntities db = new WEBEntities();

            var resultado = db.T_PDV
                            .Join(db.T_CRM_StatusPDV, t1 => t1.CNPJ, t2 => t2.DE_Cnpj, (t1, t2) => new { t1, t2 })
                            .Join(db.T_TarefaParceiro, p1 => p1.t1.CNPJ, p2 => p2.CNPJ, (p1, p2) => new { p1, p2 })
                            .Join(db.T_OsParceiro, o1 => o1.p2.IDTarefaParceiro, o2 => o2.IDTarefaParceiro, (o1, o2) => new { o1, o2 })
                            .Join(db.T_Acao, a1 => a1.o1.p2.IDAcao, a2 => a2.IDAcao, (a1, a2) => new { a1, a2 })
                            .Join(db.T_ProximaAcao, x1 => x1.a2.IDAcao, x2 => x2.IDAcao, (x1, x2) => new { x1, x2})
                            .Where(cn => cn.x1.a1.o2.NumOs == Convert.ToInt32(_osparceiro))
                            .Select(i => new { });

            return lista;
        }
```

Gostaria que se _cnpj fosse NULL ou Vazia, carregar como está, senão eu faço um where com _cnpj e _osparceiro. Tem como?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei direito como é a comparação com `_cnpj`, mas creio que a linha abaixo é bem próxima do que você precisa.

```
.Where(cn => (cn.x1.a1.o2.NumOs == Convert.ToInt32(_osparceiro)) && (_cnpj == "" || cn.cnpj == _cnpj))
```

Comment: Acho que não me fiz entender. Eu só parto para comparar o cnpj, se o mesmo for not null ou not vazio, porque é uma forma de eu ter uma consulta só por um parâmetro ou por ambos.

Comment: Mas então. A primeira parte verifica se ele é nulo ou vazio, ou seja, `_cnpj == ""` (`String` é tipo por referência, então o nulo devolve sempre vazio). Se não for vazio, verifica a próxima condição, no caso, `cn.cnpj == _cnpj`. Entendeu?

Comment: é entendi. Que às vezes o processamento da cuca tem um delay.